# Search column for text, if found, then paste cells to other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am brand new to VBA. I would like to be able to search column D for text on `Week 1` sheet, and if there is any text, then find the last text in column C, then paste both of these values on the sheet `Notetakers` to the next available column, pasting in rows 5 and 6.

So far, this is what I have:

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    Sheets("Week 1").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To FinalRow
        Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Notetakers").Select
            NextRow = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Week 1").Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

but I am getting error 424: object required for this. I have double checked that these sheets are being correctly referred to. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: Let us say that a value is found in `D3` and the first available column is column `F`. You possibly (?) want to copy the value in `D3` to `F5`. But what do you want to copy to `F6`? Because in the code you are doing something with column `A`, while in the description you are talking about column `C` also saying *last text*, where I would expect associated value i.e. the value in the same row. I know these are different worksheets. Please do clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not clear what you need to accomplish with this, but purely from the syntax perspective, you assign the cell value to variable Value in

```
Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
```

yet you test cel.Value if not empty

```
If cel.Value <> "" Then
```

while cel is not defined

It compiles when amended like this:

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    Sheets("Week 1").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To FinalRow
        celValue = Cells(i, 4).Value
        If celValue <> "" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Notetakers").Select
            NextRow = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Week 1").Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Generally I would recommend to test values etc. via regular excel functions before employing VBA, which is soooo sloooow, if nothing else.